# How to make a process running always and execute a function at specific time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, process

I want to make a process/system that should be in a running state constantly and execute a specific function at a specific time period.

For example, if I want the system to send an email to a specific address every week then what should I do?

Comment: create a process, schedule it with windows scheduler... what have you tried? what is the problem?

Comment: Actually i didn't tried anything yet because i am trying to understand and that from where should i start

Comment: Best way to schedule something is to use OS  Scheduler applciation, dont try to create your scheduler, because OS scheduler is more stable, supports long timer periods and etc... so just write a process like you are doing it one time, and schedule using windows or linux scheduler

Answer (score 2):

Running always: go for Windows service
For periodic things: go for timers

So have a Windows service which maintains a timer set to trigger at the required interval and do whatever you need there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use open-source Quartz.NET scheduler(http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), which can trigger your jobs at specified times and intervals. My suggestion is to host the scheduler job in Windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example, for some tasks it's ok.

```
public class Timer : IRegisteredObject
{
    private Timer _timer;
    public static void Start()
    {
        HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(new Timer());
    }

    public Timer()
    {
        StartTimer();
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(BroadcastUptimeToClients, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));     
    }
    private void BroadcastUptimeToClients(object state)
    {
        //some action
    }

    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In Global.asax

```
   Timer.Start();
```

In your case I will agree with @ Arsen Mkrtchyan - use OS scheduler.
If you would like to use windows service, here is how would look your service:

```
partial class MyService
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    private Timer _watcherTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.ServiceName = "MyService";

        this._watcherTimer.Interval = 6000;
        this._watcherTimer.Enabled = false;
        this._watcherTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.Timer_Tick);
    }

    #endregion
}

partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    public MyService()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error("Error initializing service",e);
            Stop();
        }

    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _watcherTimer.Enabled = true;
        logger.Info("Service has started at " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongDateString());
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        logger.Info("Service has stopped at " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongDateString());
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        logger.Info("Timer Tick");
    }
}
```

Installer:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class WindowsServiceInstaller : Installer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Public Constructor for WindowsServiceInstaller.
    /// - Put all of your Initialization code here.
    /// </summary>
    public WindowsServiceInstaller()
    {
        var serviceProcessInstaller =
                           new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

        //# Service Account Information
        serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        serviceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
        serviceProcessInstaller.Password = null;

        //# Service Information
        serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "MY SERVICE DISPLAY NAME";
        serviceInstaller.Description = "MY SERVICE DESCRIPTION";
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

        //# This must be identical to the WindowsService.ServiceBase name
        //# set in the constructor of WindowsService.cs
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "MyService";

        Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);
        Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
    }
}
```

Run this with .bat

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            //Install service
            if (args[0].Trim().ToLower() == "/i")
            { System.Configuration.Install.ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { "/i", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location }); }

            //Uninstall service                 
            else if (args[0].Trim().ToLower() == "/u")
            { System.Configuration.Install.ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location }); }
        }
        else
        {
            var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyService() };
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

install.bat

```
    @ECHO OFF

    REM Prevent changing current directory when run bat file as administrator on win7

    @setlocal enableextensions
    @cd /d "%~dp0"

    REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0

    set DOTNETFX4=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
    set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX4%

    echo Installing WindowsService...
    echo  "%CD%\WindowsService\Service\bin\Debug\Service.exe"
    echo ---------------------------------------------------
    InstallUtil /i "%CD%\WindowsService\Service\bin\Debug\Service.exe"
    echo ---------------------------------------------------
    echo Done.
    set /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...
```

unistall.bat

```
     @ECHO OFF

     REM Prevent changing current directory when run bat file as administrator on win7

     @setlocal enableextensions
     @cd /d "%~dp0"

     REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0

     set DOTNETFX4=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
     set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX4%

     echo Installing WindowsService...
     echo ---------------------------------------------------
     InstallUtil /u "%CD%\WindowsService\Service\bin\Debug\Service.exe"
     echo ---------------------------------------------------
     echo Done.
     set /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...
```

my folder hierarchy:

```
    install.bat
    uninstall.bat
    service-project-folder
       packages
       project-folder
       .sln file
```

Answer (score 0):

By making use of ReactiveExtensions you could use the following code if you were interested in doing something as simple as printing to the console as in your currently on hold question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473281/how-to-print-a-string-in-c-sharp-after-every-1-minute-using-timer. You can add Reactive Extensions by adding Rx-Main via NuGet.

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplicationExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
            .Subscribe(_ =>
            {                   
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            });
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString()); 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```